# result-view. Match. Multiple from-output

Tags: bixby

I have main result-view which matching CommandResult (commandResult)

This response can be from different actions, how I can catch all commandResult in one match in from-output?

Example:

```js
result-view {
  match: CommandResult (commandResult) {
    from-output: Command1Context    
    from-output: Command2Context    
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want ONE result-view for all CommandResult, you can remove `from-output`. Think it this way, if you don't specify any `from-output`, you get all for free.

Have fun with Bixby!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this

1. The simplest way is to create two different Views, each specific to the action that outputs them.
2. If you would rather have just a single View then you may want to look at 'information' (some sort of state information like a value, a variable etc inside CommandResult) that necessitates having a separate View. You can then review this information in the View or Layout and decide on what content needs to be displayed.

Hope this helps.